# Include directory itself in TeamCity build artifact

Tags: teamcity

In my TeamCity build config > General Settings > Artifact paths, I have as followed:

```
%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/build/libs/*.jar => install.zip
%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/build/config => install.zip
%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/build/resources => install.zip
```

The `install.zip` contains the jar and files under `config` and `resources` folders WITHOUT the folders themselves.

How do I include these directories into `install.zip`? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the folder where you want to store inside the .zip:

```
/build/libs/*.jar => install.zip 
/build/config => install.zip!Config
/build/resources => install.zip!resources
```

The specified .zip will be something like :

```
./
|_ Config
|_ resources
|_ MyLibrary.jar
|_ MyLib2.jar
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! this works! Just minor edit though: `install.zip!config` (without the slash after the exclamation mark)